Get Child records to parent and Child’s to Child
I have 2 objects, Account and Connection__c. Account : Account is many:many, e.g. a Business account can be linked to multiple Individual Accounts and one Individual can be linked to multiple Businesses.
This many:many relationship is build with a Junction object called ‘Connection__c’. This has 2 fields; Connection_From__c and Connection_To__c, where from is the parent and to the child.
I have this scenario:
From business 1 we connect to business 2.
From business 2 we connect to multiple individuals.
I’m trying to get the child & related records to child via Business 1. Getting the child’s is simple;
SELECT Connected_To__c from Connection__c where Connected_From__c = Business1.id
Keeping in mind that this can be a list of Id’s, how do I then iterate over the queried Id’s (in this example ‘Business 2’) to grab Connected_To__c from connection records where Connected_From__c is included in the first query?
Thanks for helping out!
Edit -
The current Apex code that I have is this:


public with sharing class AAAATree{
    
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<LLC_BI__Connection__c> getConnection(Id Parent) {

List<LLC_BI__Connection__c> Child = [SELECT LLC_BI__Ownership_Percent__c, LLC_BI__Connected_To__c, LLC_BI__Connected_From__c FROM LLC_BI__Connection__c WHERE LLC_BI__Connected_From__c= :Parent]; 

Set<Id> ChildIds = new Set<Id>();
for (LLC_BI__Connection__c conn : Child) {
        ChildIds.add(conn.LLC_BI__Connected_To__c);

}

List<LLC_BI__Connection__c> Grandchild = [SELECT LLC_BI__Ownership_Percent__c, LLC_BI__Connected_To__c, LLC_BI__Connected_From__c FROM LLC_BI__Connection__c WHERE LLC_BI__Connected_From__c IN :ChildIds AND LLC_BI__Connected_To__c != :Parent];

Set<Id> GrandchildIds = new Set<Id>();
for (LLC_BI__Connection__c conn : Grandchild) {
        GrandchildIds.add(conn.LLC_BI__Connected_To__c);
}

List<LLC_BI__Connection__c> Individual = [SELECT LLC_BI__Ownership_Percent__c, LLC_BI__Connected_To__c, LLC_BI__Connected_From__c FROM LLC_BI__Connection__c WHERE LLC_BI__Connected_From__c IN :GrandchildIds AND LLC_BI__Connected_To__c NOT IN :ChildIds AND LLC_BI__Connected_To__c != :Parent];

List<LLC_BI__Connection__c> allConnections = new List<LLC_BI__Connection__c>();
allConnections.addAll(Child);
allConnections.addAll(Grandchild);
allConnections.addAll(Individual);

return allConnections;

}
}


----------

As you can see we're currently only returning the Child, but I want to return Child, Grandchild & Individual.
I then want to import the returned records into an LWC so that we can display the hierarchy in a tree view. I have not been able to make the LWC work yet, so there's nothing to share.

#1: Get the IDs of Business 2 connected to Business 1
List<Connection__c> business2Connections = [SELECT Connected_To__c FROM Connection__c WHERE Connected_From__c = :business1Id];

Set<Id> business2Ids = new Set<Id>();
for (Connection__c conn : business2Connections) {
        business2Ids.add(conn.Connected_To__c);
}

#2: Get the Individuals connected to Business 2
List<Connection__c> individualConnections = [SELECT Connected_To__c FROM Connection__c WHERE Connected_From__c IN :business2Ids];

#1 Retrieves the Connected_To__c IDs where Connected_From__c is Business1Id.
#2 Uses the IDs from the #1 query to find all Connected_To__c where Connected_From__c is in the set of IDs from the #1 query.
Update:
Apex:
public with sharing class AAAATree {
        @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
        public static List<LLC_BI__Connection__c> getConnection(Id Parent) {
                List<LLC_BI__Connection__c> Child = [SELECT LLC_BI__Ownership_Percent__c, LLC_BI__Connected_To__c, LLC_BI__Connected_From__c FROM LLC_BI__Connection__c WHERE LLC_BI__Connected_From__c= :Parent]; 

                Set<Id> ChildIds = new Set<Id>();
                for (LLC_BI__Connection__c conn : Child) {
                        ChildIds.add(conn.LLC_BI__Connected_To__c);
                }

                List<LLC_BI__Connection__c> Grandchild = [SELECT LLC_BI__Ownership_Percent__c, LLC_BI__Connected_To__c, LLC_BI__Connected_From__c FROM LLC_BI__Connection__c WHERE LLC_BI__Connected_From__c IN :ChildIds];

                Set<Id> GrandchildIds = new Set<Id>();
                for (LLC_BI__Connection__c conn : Grandchild) {
                        GrandchildIds.add(conn.LLC_BI__Connected_To__c);
                }

                List<LLC_BI__Connection__c> Individual = [SELECT LLC_BI__Ownership_Percent__c, LLC_BI__Connected_To__c, LLC_BI__Connected_From__c FROM LLC_BI__Connection__c WHERE LLC_BI__Connected_From__c IN :GrandchildIds];

                List<LLC_BI__Connection__c> allConnections = new List<LLC_BI__Connection__c>();
                allConnections.addAll(Child);
                allConnections.addAll(Grandchild);
                allConnections.addAll(Individual);

                return allConnections;
        }
}

LWC:
JS:
import { LightningElement, wire, api, track } from 'lwc';
import getConnection from '@salesforce/apex/AAAATree.getConnection';

export default class TreeComponent extends LightningElement {
        @api recordId;
        @track treeItems = [];
        @track error;

        @wire(getConnection, { Parent: '$recordId' })
        wiredConnections({ error, data }) {
                if (data) {
                        this.treeItems = this.transformData(data);
                        this.error = undefined;
                } else if (error) {
                        this.error = error;
                        this.treeItems = [];
                }
        }

        transformData(data) {
                let treeItems = [];
                let connectionMap = new Map();

                // Organize data into a map based on Connected_From__c
                data.forEach(item => {
                        if (!connectionMap.has(item.LLC_BI__Connected_From__c)) {
                                connectionMap.set(item.LLC_BI__Connected_From__c, []);
                        }
                        connectionMap.get(item.LLC_BI__Connected_From__c).push({
                                label: `Connected To: ${item.LLC_BI__Connected_To__c}`,
                                name: item.Id,
                                expanded: true,
                                items: [],
                        });
                });

                // Recursively build the tree structure
                const buildTree = (parentId) => {
                        let children = connectionMap.get(parentId) || [];
                        children.forEach(child => {
                                child.items = buildTree(child.name);
                        });
                        return children;
                };

                treeItems = buildTree(this.recordId);
                return treeItems;
        }
}

HTML:
<template>
        <template if:true={treeItems}>
                <lightning-tree items={treeItems}></lightning-tree>
        </template>
        <template if:true={error}>
                <p>{error}</p>
        </template>
</template>

XML:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
        <apiVersion>60.0</apiVersion>
        <isExposed>true</isExposed>
        <targets>
                <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
                <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
                <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>

You can include this component in a Lightning Record Page, Home Page, App Page or another component and pass the parentId as an attribute:


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
